# Can we create a Native android application using python?

Tags: java, python, android, native

I want to Create an Application that is build using python language with native . But I am not getting anything

Comment: trying to write a android app in python is like trying to make apple juice with an orange, google have built so many great features into kotlin making it so powerful allowing devs to create wonderful apps, python isn't even mentioned once in any of the documentations. if you really are looking to make an android app then use kotlin, it will serve you well in the future if you decide to become a android dev, doing in python will not help you in anyways in terms of learning a skill.

Comment: I have made a machine learning project using python for desktop but i am not sure that the features as same implemented for desktop application will support android in other languages . There is way using java but it will be difficult to convert that code in java .So i was trying to find the alternate .

Comment: Oh ok , but if you feel like this application will be important in achieving your goals, i will highly recommend you to learn kotlin , it would take you a week maximum , in return you will gain a brand new highly demand skill. Best of luck

Comment: Sure i Will learn , and thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, native applications are written in a language that the platform you want to develop the application for supports. For example, native android solutions would be applications written in Java or Kotlin, for iOS apps written in Swift. To the best of my knowledge, Android does not support Python for the development of an application.

Answer (score 1):

Native Android applications can only be written in Java or Kotlin languages. Kotlin is currently the official language for coding Android Apps due to its many advantages over Java e.g Reduces boilerplate codes. It also introduces functional features to support Java interoperability.

You can also code android applications using  C and C++ languages by Installing the NDK and CMake.